# How do I setup Oh My Posh inside conemu, without using powershell?

Tags: command-line, conemu, oh-my-posh

I can get it to work in powershell, but I do most of my coding/work, just for fun, using normal command prompt/batch files,etc.

But can't get it to invoke the init or theme, got it to work fine on powershell.

But I really would like this to work in non-powershell.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to CMD, you can follow the guide to set that up using our [guide](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/installation/prompt).

Comment: That worked, i had figure out where clink scripts folder was, but that worked thank you.

Comment: Now have to figure out how to get the theme set/changed at init.

Comment: There's a second page for that ;-) https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/installation/customize#config-syntax

Comment: Thank you, thank you. Got the font figured out.